# Unable to obtain output using excel VBA (when yrs of investment > 25 or when return is less than certain amount)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, irr

I am trying to calculate the IRR for insurance policies using VBA. The four input variables are total premium paid, Years of Payment, Number of Policy Years and Final expected value.

I am able to obtain the correct IRR% when the number of Policy Years is **10**, but when I change to a higher / lower number of policy years such as **30** or **3**, the output is "#VALUE!" as shown in the picture below. Moreover, this issue also appears when the final expected value is less than a certain amount.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFbNy.png)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1glS.png)

However, i am able to find the correct IRR value when using the in-built function in excel

[IRR excel function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKUsc.png)

May i know what is causing the limitations in my code? thanks

```
Function CIRR(TotalPremiumPaid As Double, YearsOfPayment As Integer, PolicyYears As Integer, FinalValue As Double) As Double
    Dim EachValue As Double
    Dim CashFlow() As Double
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim InitialGuess As Double

    ' Calculate the annual premium payment
    EachValue = TotalPremiumPaid / YearsOfPayment

    ' Resize the cash flow array based on the total policy years
    ReDim CashFlow(0 To PolicyYears)

    ' Fill the cash flow array with negative values for the years of payment
    For n = 0 To YearsOfPayment - 1
        CashFlow(n) = -1 * EachValue
    Next n

    ' Fill the remaining years with zero (no cash flow)
    For n = YearsOfPayment To PolicyYears
        CashFlow(n) = 0
    Next n

    ' Add the final value at the end of the policy
    CashFlow(PolicyYears) = FinalValue
    
    ' Provide an initial guess for IRR calculation
    InitialGuess = 0.1 ' 10% as a starting point

    ' Calculate and return the IRR
    CIRR = IRR(CashFlow, InitialGuess)
End Function
```

Comment: For one thing, your example has 5 years of payment with 3 policy years. That doesn't make sense, and your code implicitly assumes that that it can't happen. So check for that situation.

Comment: thanks for the noticing the error here @Paul, however, it seems like the error output also appear when the policy year = 6, and the final expected value is less than 75000. But it should allow for the expected value to be less than the investment amount

Comment: Aside from that error, the initial guess is too high. Excel's IRR formula works well for fairly normal situations, but it fails in many combinations if you use the default 10%. Try 1% or 5% instead; it works for all the situations you mentioned.

Comment: I tried your method and it worked. Thanks a lot